# Conversion de archivos multiples

Tags: batch

Tengo un software (txmake) que convierte imágenes a formato `.tex`. En `cmd` uso este comando

```
D:\tmp>txmake demi.jpg demi.tex
```

¿Que comando puedo escribir para hacer que haga la conversión de todas las imágenes `jpg` dentro de la carpeta?

Answer (score 0):

Usa FOR.  Por ejemplo

```
for %a in (*.jpg) do txmake %~a.jpg %~a.tex
```

Si lo hace dentro de un archivo, cambia el % hasta %%

```
for %%a in (*.jpg) do txmake %%~a.jpg %%~a.tex
```